# Can you ever assume typecasting pointers is safe?

Tags: c, function, pointers, casting, sizeof

I've heard from many people that you cannot guarantee typecasting will be performed lossless. Is that only true if you don't know your processor, that is, you haven't verified the number of bytes used for your data types?  Let me give an example:

If you execute the following:

```
typedef struct
{
    int i;
    char c;
    float f;
    double d;
} structure;

size_t voidPtrSz = sizeof(void *);
size_t charPtrSz = sizeof(char *);
size_t intPtrSz = sizeof(char *);
size_t floatPtrSz = sizeof(float *);
size_t doublePtrSz = sizeof(double *);
size_t structPtrSz = sizeof(structure *);
size_t funcPtrSz = sizeof(int (*)(float, char));

printf("%lu\n", voidPtrSz);
printf("%lu\n", charPtrSz);
printf("%lu\n", intPtrSz);
printf("%lu\n", floatPtrSz);
printf("%lu\n", doublePtrSz);
printf("%lu\n", structPtrSz);
printf("%lu\n", funcPtrSz);
```

…and the output is the following…

```
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
```

Can you assume that in all cases you can typecast a specific data type pointer to another data type pointer safely? For example, if you execute this:

```
int foo(float, char)
{
}

void *bar(void)
{
    return (void *)foo;
}

int (*pFunc)(float, char) = bar();
```

Can you assume with certitude that `pFunc` has the address of `foo`?

Comment: The *size* of a pointer will, on all modern platforms, always be the same (on a specific system). There may be platforms where that's not true, especially for pointers to functions. However, your specific use of function pointers is safe.

Comment: Read 6.3.2.3 of the C99 language standard to see what conversions are defined and which are undefined.  (Hint: your last code example invokes undefined behaviour...)

Comment: I believe that if you `typedef void (*vf_p)();` and change the return type and cast in `bar` from `void *` to `vf_p`, then the code will do what you want.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: it's not. A function pointer may only be converted to another function pointer type, not to `void*`.

Comment: OT: To print `size_t` use `"%zu"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can you assume that in all cases you can typecast a specific data type pointer to another data type pointer safely?

Any data pointer can be safely cast to `char*` or `void*`. Any `char*` or `void*` thus created can be cast back to its original type. Any other data pointer cast leads to undefined behavior when indirection is performed on the pointer.

Any function pointer type can be cast to any other function pointer type, although you should not call a function through the wrong type. Casting a function pointer to `void*` or any other data pointer type results in undefined behavior.

> Is that only true if you don't know your processor, that is, you haven't verified the number of bytes used for your data types?

Even then, you're not safe. When the C standard says a construct has undefined behavior, compiler writers are free to handle the construct as they wish. The result is that even though you *think* you know a construct with UB will be handled because you know the target CPU, optimizing compilers may cut corners and generate very different code than you expect.

Comment: It may be useful to know that, if your target is POSIX rather than ISO C, void pointers _are_ currently required to be capable of representing function pointers as an extension in order to implement [dlsym](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dlsym.html).

Answer (score 6):

Regarding your specific code example, let's refer to section 6.3.2.3 of the C99 language standard:

> A pointer to `void` may be converted to or from a pointer to any incomplete or object type. A pointer to any incomplete or object type may be converted to a pointer to `void` and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.

Note that a pointer-to-function is not the same as pointer-to-object.  The only mention of pointer-to-function conversions is:

> A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a function of another type and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer. If a converted pointer is used to call a function whose type is not compatible with the pointed-to type, the behavior is undefined.

So your code example invokes undefined behaviour.

If we avoid function-pointer conversions, the following paragraph explains everything:

> A pointer to an object or incomplete type may be converted to a pointer to a different object or incomplete type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the pointed-to type, the behavior is undefined. Otherwise, when converted back again, the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.

**Note:** Converting between pointer types is a separate issue from converting and *then dereferencing* (in general, that's only valid if you're converting to `char *` and then dereferencing.)

Answer (score 1):

@Oli Charlesworth gives you a great answer.

I hope I can shed a little light on what pointer are so you can better understand pointer mechanics:

A pointer is an address. This address is the address of the first byte of your data. The type of the pointer specifies how many bytes starting from that first byte are part of the data and how those bytes encode the data.

For instance, on gcc x86, if you have a `int * p`, the value held by p tells the starting address of data, and the type of p (`int *`) tells that at that address he will interpret 4 bytes (in little endian byte-order) in two's complement signed number representation.

A `void *` pointer is a "generic pointer". The pointer still holds an address, but the pointer type doesn't specify what kind of data you find there, or even how many bytes form the data, so you can never access data through a `void *` pointer, but as answered before, you can safely convert between a pointer to void and a pointer to any incomplete or object type.

A pointer to function holds the address of a function, and the type of the pointer tells how to call that function (what parameters and of what kind) and what the function returns.